# Generic method covariance

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have problems with casting generics to interfaces, that this generics implement

```
public interface IQuery<out TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryRunner<in TQuery, out TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Execute(TQuery query);
}

public interface IQueryRunnerFactory
{        
   IQueryRunner<IQuery<TResult>, TResult> CreateHandler<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
}

public class QueryRunnerFactory : IQueryRunnerFactory
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider dependencyResolver;

   public QueryRunnerFactory(IServiceProvider dependencyResolver)
   {
       this.dependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;
   }

   public IQueryRunner<IQuery<TResult>, TResult> CreateHandler<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
   {            
       var genericType = typeof(IQueryRunner<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
       return this.dependencyResolver.GetService(genericType) as IQueryRunner<IQuery<TResult>, TResult>;
   }        
}
```

The problem is in last line. this.dependencyResolver.GetService(genericType) returns a handler as expected. But cast to interface returns null. If I cast it explicitly by () operator it throws InvalidCastException. AFAIU the problem is with `IQuery < TResult >` generic parameter. Is is not covariant, so it cannot be casted. But I cant use `out` keyword here, because it is not allowed for use in generic methods. How I should fix that problem?

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The first type parameter in IQueryRunner is contravariant, not covariant.  I suspect that is why the cast is failing.

Comment: The return service type of IServiceProvider.GetService does not necessary be the same type or any subclass of the input type. It's all depends on the implementation of the IServiceProvider you put in your QueryRunnerFactory. Here has no issue with regard to covariance